# Expandable Animation for a Horizontal ListView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I am currently working with a horizontal ListView as depicted below:

[image]

In this ListView, some items are composed of multiple cells, which are stacked within a `Stack` widget at varying angles. My goal is to create an expandable animation that triggers when these items are tapped, causing all the stacked cells to expand into a separate Horizontal ListView.

I've included the code snippet I've been using to build the cells:

```
const startAngle = -3.0;
  const endAngle = 3.0;
  final step = (endAngle - startAngle) / (seriesBooks.length - 1);
  final anglesInDegrees = List<double>.generate(
      seriesBooks.length, (index) => startAngle + step * index);
  final rotatedWidgets = List<Widget>.generate(seriesBooks.length, (index) {
    return Positioned.fill(
        child: Transform.rotate(
      angle: anglesInDegrees[index] * (pi / 180),
      child: _buildCell(seriesBooks[index]), // build the book cell
    ));
  });
  return Stack(children: rotatedWidgets);


Widget _buildCell(Book book) {
   return Stack (
    children: [
        Image(image: AssetImage('assets/cover_${book.id}.png')),
        Positioned(top: 10, right:10, child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/start.png')))
   ]);
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to implement this functionality.

Comment: I suggest using Visibility and AnimatedOpacity widgets where a new stack of Listview will show up on top of the current listview. The Visiblity class acts like IgnorePointer widgets so it doesn't register clicks when invisible. I can try create a demo for you if you can share your builder :)

Comment: @Texv my builder it just a Stack widget with image, icon and text on it.
I already use second ListView with Visibility and IgnorePointer like you said, but the main thing is the expand animation from stacked cells into this second ListView, still don't know how to implement

Comment: oh so just to clarify, is it just the animation you are stuck with? did you try using the `animations` package? https://pub.dev/packages/animations

Comment: yes, I only stuck with animation, and I have no idea to do with animations package (or flutter animation)